# Why is this compact operator a Fredholm operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space with the $L^{\infty}$ norm and let $A$: $X \rightarrow X$ be an integral operator of the following form,

\begin{equation}
Ax(s) = \lambda\int^{b}_{a}K(s,t)x(t)dt,
\end{equation}
where $K$: $[a,b] \times [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map such that $K \neq 0$ and where $\lambda$ is a constant.

I know that due to the continuity of $K$, Arzelà–Ascoli theorem implies that $A$ is compact. But in the uploaded image they say $A$ is Fredholm as well. I fail to see why, could someone help me out? 
[image]

Comment: The compact operators form an ideal in the bounded operators on $X$, so $A$ cannot be Fredholm. Indeed the Fredholm operators are (by Atkinson's theorem) exactly the operators which are invertible modulo the compacts. So if $AB - 1$ is compact, for some bounded operator $B$, we would have that $1$ is compact. Maybe I miss something ...

Comment: I am confused now, because [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Integral_operator) they say : 'In the first case (2) is called a Fredholm operator in C(D)' . In this example they assume the same Fredholm integral operator.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot in the OP

Comment: I think this could be an unfortunate breakdown in terminology. It's a Fredholm INTEGRAL operator, but not a Fredholm operator in the usual sense.

Comment: They explicitly say: 'In the first case (2) is called a Fredholm operator in C(D)', They make a distinction between Fredholm integral operator and a Fredholm operator and provide a restriction, namely if $K$ is continuous, when $A$ is a Fredholm operator.

Comment: I'm aware of what it says. There is an unfortunate overuse of terminology in functional analysis because of abrupt changes in the field. See also integral kernel.. it's not a kernel at all.

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation

Comment: Oke so the Fredholm integral of the first kind is not a Fredholm operator whereas the second kind is due to $(I-A)$.